# Passing a selection, node, or range object from Meteor client to server returns an empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, iron-router

My goal is to save a node and range object in to a MongoDB collection.

I have a Meteor application that was scaffolded via the Iron CLI.

client/templates/view/view.js

```
console.log(document.getSelection()); // Data verified on dev tools
Meteor.call('createComment', document.getSelection());
```

server/methods.js

```
Meteor.methods({
    'createComment': function(selectionObject) {
        console.log(selectionObject); // returns {} on terminal
    }
});
```

This same thing happens with Node, Selection, and Range objects. I have also tried the following to no success:

```
Meteor.call('createComment', { selection: document.getSelection() } );
```

Cheers

Comment: This is not possible because MongoDB doesn't support dom range's as a type. You may want to consider storing the source html instead

Comment: Very cool, thanks for the comment. I was under the assumption that I could store any JSON object in MongoDB. This is also using the assumption that any javascript object (including range, node, etc.) are JSON objects by default -- this assumption could be the root of my errors.

Comment: You can store JSON objects, the thing is `dom` isn't a json object but a javascript object. MongoDB supports these types: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/. The reason you get `{}` on the server before its inserted into mongo is dom isn't serializable to json so the data is left empty

Comment: @Akshat it appears doing JSON.stringify(document.getSelection()) returns an empty object. Any thoughts? Thanks for the help...feel free to submit anything as an answer to the question and I'll mark it as correct.